# protected code execution

Tags: cryptography

Is there ever going to be a processor or execution system that can execute protected code for very specific operations that heavily rely on shared secrets and authentication?

With the assumption that one could download a bit of encrypted code that only this processor has the correct private key to decrypt, and that key could potentially rotate with some frequency.

Code wise, a call would look something like, with the protected as a keyword that assumes the language/vm/etc could actually marshall/transfer and run this encrypt function within a protected space

```
  int transactionAmount=1; int transactionId=444555;
  byte[] data;
  protected { data = encrypt(transactionAmount, transactionId); }
  sendToServer(data);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this today pretty easily by leveraging TPMs for key management and perhaps Intel SGX for a more protected execution space.

The problem with such systems is always scale of operation, management and reliability. It's trivial for me to write some code, encrypt it with your public key and send it to you, it's extremely non-trivial to do this for everyone.